# Create a countdown timer given a user inputted number of minutes and seconds in mm:ss format

Tags: python

The user is prompted to enter a number of minutes and seconds in mm:ss format.
then the timer must count down one second at a time. Every second, you must print how much time remains in mm:ss format. I am having trouble figuring out how to separate the time in this format. This is what I have so far. The issue most likely lies right before the "While True" statement.

```
import time
x=input("Countdown Time Limit: ")
def countdown(time_sec):
    minutes = int(time_sec[:0])
    seconds = int(time_sec[0:])
    temp = 0
    while True:
        if seconds == -1:
            seconds = 59
            minutes -= 1
        if (seconds > 9):
            print('\r',str(temp) + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds),end='')
        else:
            print('\r',str(temp) + str(minutes) + ":" + str(temp) + str(seconds),end='')
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds -= 1
        if(minutes==0 and seconds==-1):
            break
    print('\n',"STOP")

countdown(x)
```

Comment: You will need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) the string that is input, or use [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse the time out

Answer (score 0):

Like @Alex said split input with : . Then use python formatting {:02} to add 0 for numbers.
You can also use only seconds to the count down :

```
import time
x=input("Countdown Time Limit: ")
def countdown(time_sec):
    tst = time_sec.split(':')
    minutes = int(tst[0])
    seconds = int(tst[1]) + 60 * minutes
    # no need for break
    while seconds > 0:
        # seconds (0-59) is just time in seconds modulo 60
        # and minutes time in second divided by 60 (here remove the seconds to prevent rounding)
        s = seconds % 60
        m = int((seconds - s) / 60)

        # format 2 digits with leading 0
        print("{:02}:{:02}".format(m,s))
        time.sleep(1)

        # easier to not have to worry about the 59 -> 0 test
        seconds -= 1
    
    print('\n',"STOP")

countdown(x)
```